# How to call object class function

Tags: c#, json, converters

I want to convert class to json string like newtonsoft.json do

But i can't call to function how can i do it?
First i give class function names than put them string but not call class function

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
..
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v);

  class Data
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Date { get; set; }
    }
 class lib
    {
        public String verGulum(object data)
        {
            List<string> fuctionName = GetPropertiesNameOfClass(data);
            string json = "{";
            for(int i=0;i< fuctionName.Count;i++)
            {
   == Thisproblem==          json += fuctionName[i]+":"+data.GetType()+",";
            }
            json += "}";

            return json;
        }
// all function name i take 
        public List<string> GetPropertiesNameOfClass(object pObject)
        {
            List<string> propertyList = new List<string>();
            if (pObject != null)
            {
                foreach (var prop in pObject.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    propertyList.Add(prop.Name);
                }
            }
            return propertyList;
        }
    }
main{
lib a = new lib();
            Data d = new Data();
            d.Number = 1;
            d.Name = "AAA";
            d.Date = 15;
            Console.WriteLine(a.verGulum(d));
}
```

output :
{Number,JsonConvert.Data,Name:...

Comment: Your output is unclear. Please edit

Comment: If you're already using `Newtonsoft.Json`, why are you trying to recreate the wheel; why not just use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourDataObj);` which will return a proper json string that represents this data.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ OP obviously knows about Newtonsoft.Json, there are plenty of reasons to recreate the wheel: Maybe it's for educational purposes. Sometimes square wheels are needed, too. Or maybe legal has to check for the next month whether newtonsoft's license is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote alternative your code.

```
public string alGulum(object data)
{

    Type myType = data.GetType();
    IList<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(myType.GetProperties());
    string json = "{";
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
    {

        object propValue = prop.GetValue(data, null);
        json += "\"" + prop.Name + "\"";
        if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            json +=":\"" + propValue + "\",";
        }
        else
        {
            json +=":" + propValue + ",";
        }
    }
    json += "}";
    return json;
}
```

Comment: Does this also work in cases for possible nested reference types? Can you please explain how this would solve the OP issue?

Comment: `alGulum(new { data = "json \" is broken now" });`

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ This code is used in simple cases I'm not try to write a new JsonConvert. I just help him. If you have an idea share us please.